# Multiple column sort in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know that `JTable` can sort by a single column. But is it possible to allow for multiple column sort or do I need to write the code myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can sort by multiple columns by specifying more than one sort key when calling `setSortKeys` in the [`RowSorter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) you're using.

Comment: a pity this isn't available in java5

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the TableRowSorter and the Comparator associated with it.
Example:

```
TableModel myModel = createMyTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(myModel);
TableRowSorter t = new TableRowSorter(myModel);
t.setComparator(column that the comparator works against, Comparator<?> comparator);
table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(myModel));
```

Comment: unrelated to multi-column sorts

Answer (score 2):

Look into [JXTable](http://swinglabs.org/docs/components/JXTable/tutorial.jsp).  JXTable is an extension of JTable that supports multi-column sorting, as well as other functions that JTable doesn't provide.  It's freely available from JDNC / SwingLabs.

Comment: Are you sure there? Actually the JXTable API states: "Sorting support is single column only."

Comment: Ok, but it works with filters. you just have to put shuttlesorters into a filterpipeline

Answer (score 1):

ETable from the netbeans collection.
It is part of org-netbeans-swing-outline.jar
A google search aught to turn it up.
The ETable is primarily a foundation for Outline (a TreeTable) but it has multi-column ordering built in as well as many other nice features

Answer (score 1):

"I know that Jtable can sort by a single column. But is it possible to allow for multiple column sort or do i need to write the code myself? "

Table sorting and filtering is managed by a sorter object. The easiest way to provide a sorter object is to set autoCreateRowSorter bound property to true;

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

This action defines a row sorter that is an instance of javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter.

Comment: _no_ is wrong - a JTable definitely supports multi-column sorts (see setSortKeys as mentioned in another answer), only the visual clue is showing on the primary sort column only